# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|min does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8.
I want to create my validation.

```
    public function change_password(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $userid = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;

        $validator = $request->validate([
            'old_password' => 'required',
            'new_password' => ['required|min:8',new PasswordRule()],
            'confirm_password'  =>  ['required|same:new_password',new PasswordRule()]
        ]);
....
```

Error output:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|min does not exist. in file /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php on line 1422
```

Comment: If you use `=> [rules]` syntax, you need to split everything; you can't use a mix of `|` and `rule, another`. Syntax is: `['required', 'min:8', new PasswordRule()]`

Comment: @TimLewis thank you, you gave me the answer to my own question. Battled this for hours
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74680209/1272406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass values as array. So it should be:

```
'new_password' => ['required','min:8',new PasswordRule()],
'confirm_password'  =>  ['required','same:new_password',new PasswordRule()]
```