# Laravel validation for row uniqueness

Tags: validation, laravel-9, laravel-formrequest

Working in Laravel 9, and I am doing my validations in `FormRequests`.

I have a `email_updates` table.

I have 3 columns, `email`, `product_uuid`, `affiliate_uuid`, and I am looking to enforce **row** uniqueness. An email can signup for multiple products, or even the same product from a different affiliate.

There is a shortened scenario of my data. The first 4 rows are valid.

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| email  | product_uuid | affiliate_uuid | created_at |
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| a@a.co | 3ed          | 21c            | 2022-01-01 |
| b@b.co | 46a          | 21c            | 2022-01-01 |
| a@a.co | 46a          | 21c            | 2022-01-01 |
| a@a.co | 46a          | 899            | 2022-01-01 |
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+
```

But I need the validator to refuse this row, because trio of `a@a.co`, `3ed`, `21c` have already been used before

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| a@a.co | 3ed          | 21c            | 2022-01-01 |
+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+
```

Here is the validator that I have written so far, but it does not catch my duplicate row

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required|email:rfc,dns|min:5|max:75',
                Rule::unique("email")->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where("product_uuid", $this->product_uuid)
                        ->where("affiliate_uuid", $this->affiliate_uuid);
                })
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The Laravel docs do not seem to address my situation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

I am sure that it is something simple but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was something simple and frankly dumb! I had tried so many things, that I had several broken things throughout my code. After cleaning them out, it came down to this. Using my attempt or @Osama Alma's answer broke with this error `Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|email does not exist.`

I started a new question to learn how to chain these things together. [Laravel merge eloquent validation rule with a Rule::](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74679075/1272406)

A comment on this question gave me the answer. [Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|min does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68132491/1272406)

***You can't use a mix of `|` and `rule`***

This code is validating all three, and will allow saving only if the combination of all three are unique

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => [
            'required', 'email:rfc,dns', 'min:5', 'max:75',
            Rule::unique("email")->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where("product_uuid", $this->product_uuid)
                    ->where("affiliate_uuid", $this->affiliate_uuid);
            })
        ],
    ];
}
```