# Laravel merge eloquent validation rule with a Rule::

Tags: validation, laravel-9, laravel-formrequest

How to merge eloquent validation rule with a Rule::

This is what I am attempting to run, but it chokes on the `[ ]` with `Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|email does not exist.`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => [
            'required|email:rfc,dns|min:5|max:75',
            Rule::unique('email_updates', 'email', 'product_uuid', 'affiliate_uuid')
        ],
    ];
}
```

This line works independently

```
return [
        'email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns|min:5|max:75',
];
```

This also works

```
return [
        'email' => Rule::unique('email_updates', 'email', 'product_uuid', 'affiliate_uuid'),
];
```

How do I merge these differing validation syntaxs?

Answer (score 0):

A comment on this question gave me the answer. [Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|min does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68132491/1272406)

***You can't use a mix of `|` and `rule`***

So this is my working answer

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => [
            'required', 'email:rfc,dns', 'min:5', 'max:75',
            Rule::unique('email_updates', 'email', 'product_uuid', 'affiliate_uuid')
        ],
    ];
}
```

It works, but I seemingly lost the eloquent messages that came with the `|` syntax, but that is a small price to pay.